# Null pointer exception during suit running

Tags: java

I'm new in automation testing. I tried write UI automation test scripts and create suite for them . But when I run my suit it runs only first class and throws null pointer exception. I debug my code and see that driver is null when it passes to second class. But I can't do anything to fix it. Please help me.

Here is my BaseClass

---

```
package Helpers;
import Pages.LoginPage;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.IOSMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BaseClass extends Devices {

    protected AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    protected void justSignIn() {

        try {
            Devices devices = new Devices("android", "Pixel 4 XL");
            devices.deviceManager();
            File appDir = new File("/Users/Narek/Downloads/SoloLearn.ipa");
            File newAPP = new File(appDir, "SoloLearn.ipa");
            driver = new AppiumDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), devices.caps);

        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println("Cause is : " + exp.getCause());
            System.out.println("Message is : " + exp.getMessage());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.logInToApp("demo21@sololearn.com", "password11");
    }



    @AfterSuite
    protected void teardown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

This is my one test classes

---

```
package Tests;

import Helpers.BaseClass;
import Pages.LeaderboardPage;
import Pages.PlayPage;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LeaderboardTest extends BaseClass {

    LeaderboardPage leaderboardPage;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp(){
        leaderboardPage = new LeaderboardPage(driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void openLeaderboardFOLLOWING(){

        ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("Positive test", "Open Leaderboard Following tab");
        test.log(Status.INFO, "Test is starting");

        leaderboardPage.openLeaderboard();
        if(platform.equals("android") && leaderboardPage.getFollowingTabTitle()){
            return;
        }
        else{
            String followingTabTitle = leaderboardPage.getFollowingTabTitleiOS();
            Assert.assertEquals(followingTabTitle, "FOLLOWING");
        }
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Open Leaderboard and make sure that opened 'FOLLOWING' tab");

        String followingTitle = leaderboardPage.getFollowingTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(followingTitle, "YOUR NETWORK");
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Open Leaderboard and make sure that Your Network is displayed");

        test.log(Status.INFO, "Test is over");
    }


    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void openLeaderboardLOCAL(){

        ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("Positive test", "Open Leaderboard Local tab");
        test.log(Status.INFO, "Test is starting");

        leaderboardPage.goToLocalTab();
        if(platform.equals("android") && leaderboardPage.getlocalTabTitle()){
            return;
        }
        else{
            String localTabTitle = leaderboardPage.getLocalTabTitleiOS();
            Assert.assertEquals(localTabTitle, "LOCAL");
        }
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Tap on Local and make sure that opened 'LOCAL' tab");

        String localTitle = leaderboardPage.getLocalTitle();
        if(platform.equals("android")){
            Assert.assertEquals(localTitle, "CHANGE");
        }else{
            Assert.assertEquals(localTitle, "ARMENIA");
        }
        test.log(Status.PASS, "make sure that 'CHANGE' button or ARMENIA is displayed");

        test.log(Status.INFO, "Test is over");
    }


    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void openLeaderboardGLOBAL(){

        ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("Positive test", "Open Leaderboard Global tab");
        test.log(Status.INFO, "Test is starting");

        leaderboardPage.goToGlobalTab();
        if(platform.equals("android") && leaderboardPage.getGlobalTabTitle()){
            return;
        }
        else{
            String globalTabTitle = leaderboardPage.getGlobalTabTitleiOS();
            Assert.assertEquals(globalTabTitle, "GLOBAL");
        }
        test.log(Status.PASS, "Tap on Global and make sure that opened 'GLOBAL' tab");

        String globalTitle = leaderboardPage.getGlobalTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(globalTitle, "LEADERS");
        test.log(Status.PASS, "make sure that 'LEADERS' title is displayed");
        leaderboardPage.backFromLeaderboard();

        test.log(Status.INFO, "Test is over");
    }



}
```

And this is my suite.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name = "Test" verbose="1">
    <test name = "teeeeeeessssttt">
        <classes>
            <class name = "Tests.LeaderboardTest" />
            <class name = "Tests.ProfileTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: add more appropriate tags, I am not into topic, so can't suggest ones, but I guess they are appium, selenium and testng?

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain clearly where (i.e. on what line) the `NullPointerException` is being thrown.

I think that there are two possibilities:

1. For some reason `justSignIn` is not being called.  I don't see any reason why ... but maybe there is something I have missed.
2. Your `justSignIn` method is being called, but an exception is thrown and handled before a value is assigned to `driver`.  Your handler should *should* be printing a stacktrace, but I guess it is possible that you have not looked in the appropriate log file to see it.

Catching all exceptions and then proceed to use the `null` driver is a really bad idea.  You would be better of letting all exceptions propagate so that TestNG can bail out of the test suite.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The NullPointerException is being thrown in second class on first test's first line.

Comment: Get rid of the try / catch in `justSignIn` and add the checked exceptions to the method signature.

Comment: I try that but doesn't help.

Comment: Of course.  You now need to find out why you were getting the exception in the first place.  Then you fix **that** problem.

Comment: I guess it is also possible that one of your testcases is assigning `null` to `driver`.  If that is the problem, it serves you right for declaring `driver` as `protected` rather than declaring a getter method (and no setter method).